# java and c++ Clien/server

Tags: java, android, c++, qt, tcp

I made a TCP sever with Qt on windows and I want to make my android app discuss with the server. 
I was able to connect my app with the server now i want to send a packet to the server I found a way but I will have to change almost all the server code source. 
The solution is to use a `outputStream` or a `DataStream` with android, I know exactly what to do with Qt but i don't know and I don't find the equivalence on Java, can somebody can help me please ? thank you :)

the code of the server:

```
QDataStream in(idClient);

if (tailleMessage == 0)
{
if (idClient->bytesAvailable() < (int) sizeof(quint16))
    return;
in >> tailleMessage;
}
if (idClient->bytesAvailable() < tailleMessage)
return;

in >> type;
tailleMessage = 0;
```

the code of my windows client:

```
  QByteArray typeToServer;
    QDataStream typeOut(&typeToServer, QIODevice::WriteOnly);

    QString type = typeDonnees;
    typeOut << (quint16) 0;
    typeOut << type;
    typeOut.device()->seek(0);
    typeOut << (quint16) (typeToServer.size() - sizeof(quint16));

    socket->write(typeToServer);
```

I want make something like this with my androis apps instead of (if i use this code i will force to change the code of my server and my window client in order to `readLine`):

```
        String str = text01.getText().toString();
        int a= str.length();
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                true);
        out.println(a);
        out.println(str);
```

Comment: `OutputStream` is completely abstract, it dependents how are you going to send and receive data? maybe you need `BufferedReader`.

Comment: Can you show the code you have tried and what is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are after?

```
private void createClient() throws IOException {
    Socket client = new Socket("server",22222);
    String text = "hello"
    // you can specify encoding of text to bytes by default java is UTF-8
    byte[] message = text.getBytes("ASCII"); 
    // encode length as 2 bytes (short integer) using big endian
    byte[] length = new byte[2];
    length[0] = (byte)(message.length >> 8);
    length[1] = (byte)(message.length & 0x0ff);
    // write message length to socket
    client.getOutputStream().write(length);
    // write message to socket
    client.getOutputStream().write(message);
    client.getOutputStream().close();
    client.close();
    System.out.println("client closed");
}
```

this is the same as above but only does one output write.

```
private void createSingleWriteClient() throws IOException {
    Socket client = new Socket("localhost",22222);
    String text = "hello";
    // you can specify encoding of text to bytes by default java is UTF-8
    // encode length as 2 bytes (short integer) using big endian
    byte[] bytes = text.getBytes("UTF-16");
    byte[] message = new byte[2+bytes.length];
    message[0] = (byte)(bytes.length >> 8);
    message[1] = (byte)(bytes.length & 0x0ff);
    System.arraycopy(bytes, 0, message, 2, bytes.length);
    // write message to socket
    client.getOutputStream().write(message);
    client.getOutputStream().close();
    client.close();
    System.out.println("client closed");
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank for your answer i tried your code i think it's may be the solution, I receive the length (5) but not the message.Could you explain me what is the role of these lines  ``length[0] = (byte)(text.length() >> 8);``
    ``length[1] = (byte)(text.length() & 0x0ff);``

Comment: that is to encode the length as a 2 byte integer. you could write it directly as two byte writes. It is curious that the message did not come through. It worked on my test example. Do you recall your read method until the message it read? You could also merge the two writes into one.

Comment: Yes i recall my read method until my message is read but the only thing i receive are the message lenght and an empty string something weird happened here ``if (idClient->bytesAvailable() < tailleMessage)
return;

in >> type;`` . In this line why do you put an hexadecimal number  ``length[1] = (byte)(text.length() & 0x0ff);``

Comment: habit whenever I do integer conversion I mask to be safe, it is not  needed in this case.

Comment: It looks like QStrings are UTF-16 encoded this is probably causing problems UTF-16 characters are typically 2 bytes wide.

Comment: it's still not working, it's very weird because i receive the length but i receive an empty string

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a C++ server and a Java client (being Android app), your safest choice is to stick to a text (potentially compressed/encrypted) protocol that is compatible with both: XML or JSON. Both C++ and Java have support for either.

Comment: It's really bad some developers prefer fat string based formats over pure primitive data types, and the reason is just because they are easy to understand. why should I convert the(for example)a long value into string and then parse it to long again!? extra/idle processors?!

Comment: What I said above is a good _general-purpose_ rule. It is not mandatory for each and every situation. It has many advantages (portability, extensibility, ease of debugging). Obviously, for high-performance, latency-sensitive cases one should consider passing binary data with minimum conversions.

Comment: I see you buddy, I mention it as general too. anyway good answer.

Comment: This is not a problem but a problem of storage of data reception